# Finishing an Activity with onBackPressed()

Tags: android

I have two activities like First and Second.I direct to Second activity from First activity by clicking a button.I start again the First activity from Second activity after doing some works.So the some values are updated accordingly. When I come back to the First activity, I call the finish() method.So If I press the phone back button the second activity does not start.But the problem is when I click the back button now It direct to the First activity which had the previous data(Data when I started the app.)I want to stop this.I want to finish my First activity when press back button.If the question is unclear please let me know.I want to solve this.

example:
A(original state) -> B(Second activity) -> A(Updated state).
When I go from B -> A(Updated state) and press back button from A.Again it direct to the A(original state).I want to stop this and want to finish the application when back button press from A(updated state)

Comment: You could finish your First activity when starting the Second Activity. May this help?

Comment: this is the proper way for what you want to do: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: Pass values from `ActivityB` to `ActivityA` using `setResult(value)`. And receive it in `onActivityResult()` of `ActivityA`.

Comment: Thank you every body.Can't I finish activity with out using onActivityResult() ?Because in activity B I am sending data to a web service and when go fro B -> A the activity A is updated by calling a web Service and use data which send from B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start second activity use `startActivityForResult()`. Instead, start an activity, that way second activity starts as a child activity, and when you close second activity, you will come back to first activity and a callback method will be invoked `onActivityResult()` where you can update your status, now if you press back button your app will close.

1. start Activity B from Activity A

   ```
   startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
   ```
2. before finishing Activity B

   ```
   setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
   finish();
   ```
3. on Activity A

   ```
   @Override 
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       // Check which request we're responding to
       if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
           // Make sure the request was successful
           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           // get your data and use it
           }
       } 
   }
   ```

Here is [an example](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example) of `startActivityForResult()`

Answer (score 1):

put this line when your moving from second activity to first activity(from B -> A)

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

It will clear activity stack

Another way to do is,
dont start activity A second time, just pass your data from activity B using setData and get All those data in activity A onActivityResult()

Comment: Thank you very much.But Can't I finish activity with out using onActivityResult() ?Because in activity B I am sending data to a web service and when I go from B -> A again, the activity A is updated by calling a web Service and use data which send from B

Comment: in that case , it is good to use ` intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); `

Answer (score 1):

You could call `finish()` function for each time you move to other Activity by function: 
`startActivity()` like following:

A -> B:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, B.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```